# A seq of tuple with adhoc types?

Tags: f#

I have the following function to set the Http header of `HttpWebRequest`.

```
type Http private() =
    ....
    static member InnerRequest(url:string, forceText, ?query, ?headers, ....)
        ....
        for header, value in headers do // : #seq<string * string>
            match header with
            | StringEquals "accept" -> req.Accept <- value 
            | ....
            | _ -> req.Headers.[header] <- value)
```

I can pass the function a `seq` of `string * string`.

```
let headers = [
    "accept", "*/*";
    "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"; 
    "Accept-Charset", "UTF-8,*;q=0.5" ]
```

However, I also want to set `KeepAlive` and `AlowAutoRedirect` which have the type of `bool`. The follow code will fail.

```
let headers = [
    "accept", "*/*";
    "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"; 
    "Accept-Charset", "UTF-8,*;q=0.5";
    "KeepAlive", true ] // cannot have bool here
```

What's the good way to implement it in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [discriminated union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) would be the F#-ish way to do it; you can use one case for `string` valued things and another for `bool` valued things.

Given that for some cases in your pattern-match you are explicitly setting a particular property, it may also sense to have a case for each of those separately:

```
type Headers =
    | StringHeader of string * string
    | BoolHeader of string * bool
    | Accept of string
    ...
```

then

```
let headers =
    [Accept "*/*" ;
     StringHeader ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch") ;
     BoolHeader ("KeepAlive", true) ]
```

and in your `InnerRequest` code:

```
for header in headers do
    match header with
    | StringHeader (name, value) -> req.Header.[name] <- value
    | BoolHeader (name, value) -> ... // however you set a bool property
    | Accept value -> req.Accept <- value 
    | ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It will be a big discriminated union. I've updated the question and it shows that a lot of headers are set by `req.Headers.[header] <- value`. Is there any way which doesn't use discriminated union?

Comment: Just make two cases, one which is a `string*string` and the other which is a `string*bool`.